# Speed Up Sonarqube Scan

Tags: java, performance, sonarqube

We have a Java Project with about 95k LOC and our Sonar Scan takes about 5 minutes. We execute the sonar scan with Gradle on Jenkins. Do you know a way how to speed up the scan? I have searched to scan only the modified files but I did not found something.

Thanks in advance

Edit: Gradle configuration:

```
buildscript {
   classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.2"
}

apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
apply from: 'sonar.gradle'
```

and in sonarqube.gradle:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.host.url", sonarServerUrl
        property "sonar.projectKey", projectKey
        property "sonar.projectVersion", version.toString()
        if (sonarBranchName != 'master') {
            property "sonar.branch.name", sonarBranchName
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Would be nice if you provided code and test inputs.

Comment: Did you check the hardware requirements in the documentation?

Comment: @JeroenHeier our build servver has 8 physical cores and 16 virtual cores and 32 GB RAM these performance issues also occures when sonar qube is the only running build.